# Could not find or load main class using JavaExec with gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, program-entry-point

I java Groovy project wit main class

**MainRss.groovy**

```
package com.example.rss.core
public class MainRSS {
    static void main(String args[]) {
        Parser parser = new Parser()
        parser.parseMainRss()
    }
}
```

**buidl.gradle**

```
task parseMainRss(type: JavaExec) {
    description = 'This task will start the main class of the MainRSS'
    group = 'RSSFeed'
    main = 'com.example.rss.core.MainRSS'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

}
```

when execute

**gradle parseMainRss**

I have output:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:parseMainRss
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.rss.core.MainRSS
:parseMainRss FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':parseMainRss'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Why com.example.rss.core.MainRSS is not found it is specified as fully qualified name?

Comment: Where exactly did you put the Groovy source file? Does `build/classes/main/com/example/rss/core/MainRSS.class` exist after executing the build?

Comment: oo it was not in src/main/groovy. I change it and now it works. It is not good to work late at nights. Thanks, Peter.